# How To Fix inspect Element Bug/Errors in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

My problem is what if someone changes hidden input field value and set to another id in this example value is "2", and imagine that attacker comes and changes value to "3". Now problem is I'm taking value through hidden input field if attacker change value it will delete user of changed value!.. Help Me.

**Code**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uhi" value="2" id="uhi">
<button class="btn btn-frd" name="addfrdbtn" id="addfrdbtn" type="button">Follow</button>
```

Comment: Your PHP needs to check whether the current user is allowed to delete that piece of data. This is the process known as authorisation. Every piece of data coming from the browser should be validated and, if necessary, checked for authorisation permissions, as a matter of routine. Hidden fields are not the only issue, any input is potentially a threat.

Comment: (the button in your question is called "follow" though, so why would it delete anything?)

Comment: In addition, create a login and check the user has logged in and if not logged in even the value is other than 2 just ignore it. And You can check whether a certain user is a correct user too. Using a PHP based framework will make those things easier since they have these features or if not there are third party libraries